# C# IBM MQ Unmanaged Client Multithread Get Message

Tags: c#, multithreading, ibm-mq

I am trying to use multiple threads to open an IBM MQ queue manager and get message from it from every thread.

I have encountered a couple of problems with the code.

1. When the threads are started, the first one or two threads will fail
   with "Object not set to an instance" error near the "pnrQ.Get(msg,
   gmo);"
2. When the subsequent threads are started, only one thread is reading messages from the queue, the other threads will all have the
   "MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR" error

Does this have something to do with the "openOptions" I declare for the Queue Manager? Or something to do with the "MQGetMessageOptions" I declare?

Where can I refer to some sample codes for IBM MQ Unmanaged Client multithread sample codes?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MqClientUnmanaged
{
    class MqClientUnmanaged
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hashtable prop = new Hashtable();
            prop.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("host"));
            prop.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("port"));
            prop.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("channel"));
            prop.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);
            prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("sslKeyRepository"));
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("cipherSpec"));
            prop.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("certLabel"));

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in prop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}, Value: {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
            }
            //MQQueueManager[] queueManager = new MQQueueManager[int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["number_of_thread"])];
            //MQQueue[] pnrQueue = new MQQueue[int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["number_of_thread"])];
            
            try
            {
                var queueManager = new MQQueueManager[int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["number_of_thread"])];
                var pnrQueue = new MQQueue[int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["number_of_thread"])];

                int openOptions = MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;

                Thread[] threads = new Thread[int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["number_of_thread"])];

                for(int thread_array_count = 0; thread_array_count < int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["number_of_thread"]); thread_array_count++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        queueManager[thread_array_count] = new MQQueueManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("queue_manager"), prop);
                        pnrQueue[thread_array_count] = queueManager[thread_array_count].AccessQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("queue"), openOptions);
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + thread_array_count.ToString() + " successfully connected to " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("queue"));
                        threads[thread_array_count] = new Thread(() => LoopMessage(thread_array_count, pnrQueue[thread_array_count]));
                        threads[thread_array_count].Name = string.Concat("Threads ", (thread_array_count).ToString());
                        threads[thread_array_count].Start();
                        Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["thread-sleep"]));
                    }
                    catch (MQException mqe)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", mqe.Message.ToString(), mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error StackTrace: {0}, {1}", mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason code: {0}", mqe.ReasonCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason: {0}", mqe.Reason);
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (pnrQueue[thread_array_count] != null)
                                pnrQueue[thread_array_count].Close();
                            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + thread_array_count.ToString() + " " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("queue") + " is closed");
                        }
                        catch (MQException mqe)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", mqe.Message.ToString(), mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error StackTrace: {0}, {1}", mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason code: {0}", mqe.ReasonCode);
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason: {0}", mqe.Reason);
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            if (queueManager[thread_array_count] != null)
                                queueManager[thread_array_count].Disconnect();
                            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + thread_array_count.ToString() + " " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("queue_manager") + " is disconnected");
                        }
                        catch (MQException mqe)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", mqe.Message.ToString(), mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error StackTrace: {0}, {1}", mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason code: {0}", mqe.ReasonCode);
                            Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason: {0}", mqe.Reason);
                        }
                    }
                }                          
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", mqe.Message.ToString(), mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error StackTrace: {0}, {1}", mqe.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason code: {0}", mqe.ReasonCode);
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error reason: {0}", mqe.Reason);
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to EXIT.......");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void LoopMessage(int thread_num, MQQueue pnrQ)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
            gmo.WaitInterval = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("wait_interval"));  //1 to 2 second wait time or MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED

            while (flag)
            {
                try
                {
                    //IMPORTANT: must declare a new message here
                    MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
                    pnrQ.Get(msg, gmo);
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread # ", thread_num.ToString() + "; Message Length = " + msg.MessageLength.ToString());
                    if(msg.MessageLength > 0)
                    {
                        string newMessage = msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength);
                        string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread # ", thread_num.ToString() + "; Message Id = " + ByteArrayToString(msg.MessageId));
                        //write to text file
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(string.Concat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("pnr_file_path"), "sbr.", thread_num.ToString(), ".", timestamp, ".", guid, ".", ByteArrayToString(msg.MessageId), ".txt")))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(newMessage);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Writing PNR file with name = ", string.Concat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("pnr_file_path"), "sbr.", thread_num.ToString(), ".", timestamp, ".", guid, ".", ByteArrayToString(msg.MessageId), ".txt")));
                        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 100));
                    }
                    // set te cursor to remove the message from the queue
                    gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR;
                    pnrQ.Get(msg, gmo);
                    gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
                }
                catch (MQException mqex)
                {
                    if (mqex.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE || mqex.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR)
                    {
                        //no meesage - life is good - loop again
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread # " + thread_num.ToString() + "; MqClientUnmanaged reason code = " + mqex.ReasonCode + "; MqClientUnmanaged reason = " + mqex.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("MqClientUnmanaged reason code = " + mqex.ReasonCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("MqClientUnmanaged error message = " + mqex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("MqClientUnmanaged StackTrace = " + mqex.StackTrace);
                        flag = false;  //severe error - time to exit
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MqClientUnmanaged error message = " + ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("MqClientUnmanaged stack trace = " + ex.StackTrace);
                    flag = false;  //severe error - time to exit                 
                }
            }
        }

        private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```